# Laravel : Pass dynamic variables to routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

New to Laravel so please be patient with me, I have a route in web.php as below :

```
Route::get('/add_rcord/{formid}/{userid}', 'site_controller@add_rcord')->name('add_rcord');
```

I need to go to the URL by clicking a link while passing 2 variables as below :

```
<?php

  $value1=1;
  $value2=2; ?>
  <a href="{{route('/add_rcord/$value1/$value2')}}">Add Record</a>
```

This does not work , Can someone advise me how can I do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define the **parameter** name, if you have multiple parameter :

```
route('add_rcord', ['formid' => $value1, 'userid' => $value2])
```

Comment: $value1 and $value2 in web.php have to be dynamic values ? or inside quotes , it will give error as no variable defined ,. please guide

Comment: here `{formid}` and `{userid}` are dynamic

Comment: Thanks a lot , sorted out my issue

Comment: @stackoverflow-account can you please post your solution so it can help others?

Comment: this is the solution @Haroon route('add_rcord', ['formid' => $value1, 'userid' => $value2])